# modal popup not showing using user control asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have been trying to get an AJAX ModalPopupExtender to work from an user control in asp.net. I have tried using the dummy control to get the modal to display as well as the TargetControlID to get it to display. the closet I have gotten it to display is it flashing when the target control is clicked. I have tried calling it from code behind as well. I have added an update panel in the user control as well the actual aspx page that is calling the user control. Nothing seems to work.

The following is my code :

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="mnuLink" ID="mnuLogin" Text="<%$ Resources:share, lblLogOrreg%>">
</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Panel ID="panTerm" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100%" Height="100%">
    <asp:Panel ID="panInnerTerm" runat="server" Height="500px" Width="600px" BorderWidth="1px">
        <login:menu id="loginControl" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text="testing"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:share, btnClose%>" CssClass="button" />
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
<ajaxtoolkit:modalpopupextender id="popUpterms" runat="server" targetcontrolid="mnuLogin" behaviorid="popupCopyCtrl"
    popupcontrolid="panTerm" cancelcontrolid="btnCancel">
</ajaxtoolkit:modalpopupextender>
```

I have also tried using javascript to hide and display the panel with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what happened but after  closing and reopening visual studio the pop started to work as intended. I ended up using the dummy label approach and trigger the modalpop from code behind.

```
     <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="mnuLink" id="mnuLogin" Text="<%$ Resources:share, lbnSignIn%>"  OnClick="mnuLogin_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
           <a href="~/Account/Register.aspx" runat="server" class="mnuLink" >
        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:share, lblRegister%>"></asp:Literal></a>
        </div>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="dummylabel"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Panel ID="panLogin" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="100%" Height="100%" CssClass="modalBackground" Style="display: block;">
        <asp:Panel ID="panInnerLogin" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="300px" BorderWidth="1px" CssClass="modalPanel">
            <div id="divSign" class="centerText">
                <login:menu ID="loginControl" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:share, btnCancel%>" CssClass="button" />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="popUpLogin" runat="server" TargetControlID="dummylabel" BehaviorID="popupCopyCtrl"
        PopupControlID="panLogin" CancelControlID="btnCancel">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```